# Kotlin after taking a picture unable to upload image to Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In Kotlin, to upload an image to Firestore I want to give the users 2 options, choose image from gallery or take a picture. Choosing image from gallery works with no issue, but, if I take a picture, I'm not able to upload to Firestore.

The app fails because "imageUrl = data?.data" is null.

Here is a copy of my code, any help is greatly appreciated:

**Main Activity**

```
private fun camera() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
}

private fun gallery() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            var pic : Bitmap? = data?.getParcelableExtra<Bitmap>("data")
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(pic)
            imageUrl = data?.data //This is null
            println("From Camera...${data?.data}")
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            imageUrl = data?.data //valid
            profileImage.setImageURI(imageUrl)
            println("From Gallery...${data?.data}")
        }
    }
}


fun uploadUserImage() {
    if (imageUrl != null && userId != null) {
        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID()
        val filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
            .child("profileImages").child(userId!!).child(fileName.toString())
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUrl)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos)
        val data = baos.toByteArray()

        val uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(data)

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener { e -> e.printStackTrace() }
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            filePath.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                updateImageUrl(uri.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help a bit. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you for this info, the issue I'm having is when using the camera instead of the gallery. Using the gallery I can pick an image and upload to Firestore with no problem. If I use the camera, this is null:  imageUrl = data?.data

Answer (score 0):

To capture image from camera , you can follow the way of file provider with file creation as mentioned in documentation . Kindly check this way

https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#TaskPath

Bonus :- As `onActivityResult` is deprecated now so you should move your code to `registerForActivityResult` as shown in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930502/5696047